# Change column order of layout for mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

The image below shows my currently layout where the height of container 1 and 3 is determined by the middle column. In my mobile view, I want the containers to stack on top of each other, that is, 1,2,3,4. However with my current approach, I have 1,2,4,3

[image: Desktop view]

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="aside aside-1">
        <h2>container 1</h2>    
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner-content first">
            <h2>container 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id fermentum erat, cursus viverra risus. Cras sodales risus justo, in pretium eros pretium ut.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-content last">
            <h2>container 4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside aside-2">
        <h2>container 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>


.wrapper {
    display: flex;  
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper > * {
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.main {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    .inner-content {
        background: yellow;
        padding: 10px;
        &.first {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    }
}


.aside-1, .aside-2  {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .main    { flex: 1 0px; }
    .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
    .main    { order: 2; }
    .aside-2 { order: 3; }
    .footer  { order: 4; }
}
```

Here is a link to [demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/vsajL9rf/1/) issue

Comment: The code you have given us doesn't create the layout that you show in your image, please show us a [MRE] so we can see what you are working with and be able to help.

Comment: I have updated the question and added a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vsajL9rf/1/

Comment: The problem is with your HTML structure - In your updated code, we can see that  2 and 4 are in the same container, so that are always going to act as one unit. You are not going to be able to put another external element in between them.

Comment: I do realise that, but i wonder how i can stack 2, and 4 without grouping them in the same container. And let 1, 3's height be determined with the centre containers. If that makes sense

Comment: I'm not actually sure it's actually possible without js, if that is an option?

Comment: JS isn't an option, i'm afraid.

Comment: With your current html is not possible to reorder the items without using javascript. 
.first and .last are contained in the same container, so it is not possible to place aside-2 in the middle of both...

Comment: I am opened to changing the HTML structure... but how do i do that whilst maintaining the view of the image in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## display: contents;

With your actual markup, one of the soution would be to use `display: contents;` on `.main` div.

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes. Please note that the CSS Display Level 3 spec defines how the contents value should affect "unusual elements" — elements that aren’t rendered purely by CSS box concepts such as replaced elements.

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Box).

**Two caveats:**

- It might remove the content from the accessibility tree
- It's not supported by IE

**Snippet as follows :**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;  
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  
  .wrapper > * {
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

.main {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: contents;

  .inner-content {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 10px;

    &.first {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
}


.aside-1,
.aside-2 {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.last {
  order: 2;
}

.aside-2, .last {
  width: 100%;
 margin: 20px 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 1 0px;
    display: block;
  }

  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .main {
    order: 2;
  }

  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }

  .last {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside aside-1">
    <h2>container 1</h2>    
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner-content first">
      <h2>container 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id fermentum erat, cursus viverra risus. Cras sodales risus justo, in pretium eros pretium ut.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-content last">
      <h2>container 4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside aside-2">
    <h2>container 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Support:**

[Table of support on Can I Use](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=display%3A%20contents%3B)

---

## css grid

By changing your actual markup and using grid, you could have an easier solution.

There is many ways to do it and I would adjust the `HTML markup` depending on the importance of the content for the page.

A solution would be to have a wrapper with for children as follows : Content 1, Content 2, Content 3, Content 4.
On mobile, you can keep the initial box model `display: block;` and make the adjustement only in your media queries.

**Snippet as follows :**

```css
.wrapper > div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    gap: 20px 20px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "aside-1 first aside-2"
      "aside-1 last aside-2";
  }  
  
  .aside-2 { grid-area: aside-2; }
  .aside-1 { grid-area: aside-1; }
  .first { grid-area: first; }
  .last { grid-area: last; }  

  .wrapper > div {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="aside-1">
    <h2>container 1</h2>    
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    <h2>container 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id fermentum erat, cursus viverra risus. Cras sodales risus justo, in pretium eros pretium ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-2">
    <h2>container 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="last">
    <h2>container 4</h2>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The markup and the styles are simpler than your initial code: less div and less rules.

[Table of support on Can I Use](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=grid)

Don't forget to prefix your rules whe you use grid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The HTML is opened to change. I would rather a widely supported solution if that makes sense. How would you propose i go about it if i could change the HTML but avoid duplication.

Comment: Hello. I've updated my answer with a solution using `css grid`. Coverage should be 95.12%. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Love the answer. Thank you!! Much cleaner solution

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Are you familiar with the `grid` declaration or do you need more explications ?